# window functions in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Does Azure Cosmos DB NoSQL support window functions like rank(), row_number()? I wasn't able to find any documentation on it (or in general about how conformant it is to SQL).
I tried a simple query like

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.rating) FROM players p
```

but it gives a syntax error like "incorrect syntax near 'OVER'"

If it is not supported, how can I achieve similar functionality. My use case is that of a leaderboard where I have a players container with ratings, so for example items look like

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "rating": 175
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "rating": 220
  }
]
```

(there could be other fields, but they are not relevant)
And lets say there are 100,000 items in the container and in the current game session, four players are playing. I would like to find the rank of each player based on his/her rating. So in a relational database, the SQL query would be something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY rating) AS rank 
  FROM players
) AS p 
WHERE id IN ('1','2','3','4');
```

How can I achieve it in cosmos DB?

I have read some articles related to using a Redis cache, but that seems like an overkill to me as I currently have very little traffic (which I hope will increase gradually).

Comment: I guess I can read player data normally first and then for each player individually do a query like `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM players p WHERE p.rating > <player rating>`, but would that be performant as the size of the container increases?

Comment: There are no window functions in Cosmos DB's SQL query language (the complete language, with all options, is fully documented). I would suggest editing to show some sample data, expected vs actual output, the query you're running, etc. As written, there really isn't a way to help (as there is nothing specific to help with)

Comment: @DavidMakogon, edited, adding more details